# What would be “The Best” possible approach in given scenario?

Tags: java, android

Recently I’ve been to an interview, where I was asked to write a helper method to check if a string or list of strings are not null and not empty.

**Scenario:** In sign-up form (Android - Java), I need to check if all text fields are having content and then on click of Sign Up, appropriate action has to be shown. No need to check onTextChanged for each character input. Just check only when clicking the Sign Up button.

**Constraint:** Method should take N-number of inputs. Should not take only one input.

Below is the best possible approach that I’ve come up with:

```
public static boolean isNotEmpty(String... strList) {
    boolean isNotEmpty = true;
    for(String str : strList) {
        isNotEmpty = isNotEmpty && str != null && str.length() > 0;
    }
    return isNotEmpty;
}
```

It works as expected. But two issues here, how to break the loop as soon as isNotEmpty becomes false. I can add another condition inside loop as below, but it adds another operation for each iteration.

```
public static boolean isNotEmpty(String... strList) {
    boolean isNotEmpty = true;
    for(String str : strList) {
        isNotEmpty = isNotEmpty && str != null && str.length() > 0;
        if (!isNotEmpty) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having in consideration you're already creating an if condition when assigning to the variable "isNotEmpty" why not do the following:

```
 public static boolean isNotEmpty(String...strList) {
  for (String str: strList) {
   if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
```